# IE 6 Script error when Highstock & Highcharts are loaded

Tags: highcharts

When i Use Highstock & Highcharts together in page i am getting script error.

Here i am trying to load pie chart on click of the data point, where as the same is  it working fine with IE 8 and 9 where as the same is not working with IE  6 & 7.

Thanks in advance
Khadeer

Comment: honestly, consider upgrading to ie8 at least - lesser versions are becoming massive security risks as they receive no more patches (ie6 at least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wan t to use together Highstock and Highcharts, include ONLY Highstock - Highstock contains Highcharts.

Comment: Thanks for your comment it worked.as earlier i was referring both JS files.